# Add biographical summary in the end of a paper

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I am writing a paper using spring latex template. But i cannot add an author's biography using `\begin{biography} ... \end{biography}`, the spring class seems not providing biography environment. I find that someone have managed to use \parpic to add author's biography. Then i try to follow the same way as bellow:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{picins}
\begin{document}
\parpic{\includegraphics[width=1in,clip,keepaspectratio]{./figures/yoon2.eps}}
\noindent {\bf \small author 1} \small ...introduce author 1
\parpic{\includegraphics[width=1in,clip,keepaspectratio]{./figures/yoon2.eps}}
\noindent {\bf \small author 2} \small ...introduce author 2
\parpic{\includegraphics[width=1in,clip,keepaspectratio]{./figures/yoon2.eps}}
\noindent {\bf \small author 3} \small ...introduce author 3
\parpic{\includegraphics[width=1in,clip,keepaspectratio]{./figures/yoon2.eps}}
\noindent {\bf \small author 4} \small ...introduce author 4
\end{document}
```

all the package i used:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{flushend}  
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{picins}
```

I got this result as bellow. However the authors' photos are overlapping each other.

[image]

What i want is like the result bellow.

[image]

Anyone knows what should i add into my code to get the right result? Thanks in advance!

BTW, i am using two column format and the flushend pachage, which can automatically balance the , but it seems not work together with parpic, the four authors' biography are in one column and not balanced. Any solutions?

Comment: Please complete your MWE with a `\documentclass` - it seems to be important in this case...

Comment: I have added the \documentclass. Thanks for the reminder~

Comment: Could you please 1) copy all the code into one example in the order it is in your file 2) reduce the packages you load to a minimal set that will reproduce the bad behavior? Moreover, I don't have that documentclass on my computer, could you please provide a link to the official copy? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I finally used the biograph package instead of the parpic. It met all my needs.
download link:
https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/biograph.sty

Comment: URL https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/biograph.sty not accessible.